# Store/Retrieve same cached objects from different microservices using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I have two microservices using Springboot, 1) Client Onboarding 2) Actual Functionality API.

1. Client Onboarding: We can onboard a client to the API.
2. Uses client details by calling Client Microservices.

I'm using Redis AWS elastic cache, so I want client details to be cached by service 1, and service 2 should fetch it from the cache if it's already available in cache or call to service 1.

While deserializing the cached object I'm getting an error(Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) since the actual class is not present.

My question:

1. Is this the right approach for saving a network call as every time I need client details.
2. Is there any other way to deserialize the cached object? I could have directly cached in service 2 but service 2 will not know when to perform cache evict if any update to the client details.

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- "*Is this the right approach for saving a network call as every time I need client details.*" - I suspect the redis cache to be on a different machine as well. Hence, the query against redis will also result in a network request.

Comment: Please post here if there are any existing posts on the same, I could not find any existing posts for these questions. Coming to the original question, network call to Microservice which gives you results from DB will be slower than getting data from cache with just one network call.

Comment: how did you solve this issue?